# Getting error when trying to read multiple excel files into dataframe

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I typically run this code iteration when reading about 100 or so .xls/.xlsx files into a dataframe with `unnest`. Never a problem - now, when trying to do over 2000 files or so, I get the error `Error:` rId1 `not found` - I read that this could be because one of the files is an older format - but I confirmed all excel files are .xls (97-2003 Worksheet) or .xlsx (more modern) - the format I typically read when doing 100 or so files at a time.

I have attempted my usual iteration in the above code, and then a newer one with a for loop in the below with no luck around the **rId1** error. What could be happening?

```
files2 <- 
  list.files(path = "C:\\path",pattern = "*xls", full.names = TRUE) %>% basename() 

data <- tibble(Customer = files2) %>% # create a data frame
  mutate(file_contents = map(Customer,         
                             ~ read_excel(file.path("C:\\path", .), col_types = "text")) # a new data column and convert to text
  )
```

```
files <- 
  list.files(path = "C:\\path", pattern = "*xls")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  data <- read_excel(paste0("C:\\path", files[i]))}
```

Comment: This thread https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/408 discusses an example workbook that has a hidden worksheet that does not have an `rId` and which causes an error with the `readxl` package. I wonder if you might be able to try subsets of your set to hone in on which ones won't load, and then see if any of those have hidden sheets.

Comment: I see. Hmm. I'm not sure I can easily isolate the culprit(s) put of 2k+ excel files. I may need to see if I can do an xlsx conversion script as that seems to resolve the null id issue. Ugh

Comment: I wonder if this could be addressed using `purrr::safely` or `purrr::possibly` to run the code and flag the files for which the error arises.  https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html or this example:  https://aosmith.rbind.io/2020/08/31/handling-errors/#wrapping-a-function-with-possibly